# How to retrieve tag names in xml dynamically and store the tag name uniquely without using unique keyword in database?

Tags: php, xml

Here is my php code to retrieve node name and path. The node name is retrieved dynamically. only xml file is specified in the code.

```
<?php
$xml=file_get_contents('test.xml');

$xmlfile = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
xmlRecurse($xmlfile,0);
function xmlRecurse($xmlObj,$depth=0,$xpath=null) {
    if (!isset($xpath))//if xpath is null
    {
        $xpath='/'.$xmlObj->getName().'/';//root element
        echo $xpath."\n";
        db_store($xpath,$xpath,'nill',0);
    }
    $position = array();
    foreach($xmlObj->children() as $child) // if root has children
    {
        $name = $child->getName();  //get subchild
        //echo $name."\n";
        if(isset($position[$name])) //position name is set to any value
        { 
            ++$position[$name];
        }
        else 
        {
            $position[$name]=1; //intial value of position for first root child
        }
        $path=$xpath.$name.'['.$position[$name].']';
        // echo $xpath.$name."\n";
        echo str_repeat('-',$depth).">".$name.": $path\n";
        echo $name."\n";
        db_store($name,$path,'er',$position[$name]);
        xmlRecurse($child,$depth+1,$path.'/');
    } 
}

function db_store($name,$path,$parent,$position)
{
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost"; // Example : localhost
    $mysql_user = "root";
    $mysql_password = "";
    $mysql_database = "xmlloaddata";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$mysql_database};host{$mysql_hostname};port=3306", $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
    $name=str_replace('/','',$name);
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `xmlload` (`node`,path,parent,ref_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $sql->execute(array($name,$path,$parent,$position));
}
?>
```

XML file

```
   <items>
   <item>
   <title>Google</title>
   <url>google.com</url>
   </item>
   <item>
   <title>

   </title>
   <title>yahoo</title>
   <url>accounts.google.com</url>
   </item>
   </items>
```

This results in this manner

- items

  - item

    - title
    - url
  - item

    - title
    - url

Expected result is

- items

  - item

    - title
    - url

Help me to solve this problem

Comment: Can you edit post with XML sample (with complete tree)? Or, better, a link to your entire xml (you can use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), i.e.)

Comment: You should really provide the source XML, in the expected result you mention "color" but no such node exists in the small example you put out.